# How should I install and use multiple versions of Node on the same production machine?

Tags: node.js, nvm, n, nave

I know about `n`,`nave` and `npm` but I think that those are intended for development/testing.

Our requirement is that we be able to have more than one version of Node running on a production machine. For instance, I might want an Express app running on Node 4. Also a Koa app running on Node 5. Also a HapiJS API running on Node 6.

I don't know that `nvm` *doesn't* do this, but since it's a shell script my intuition says it won't. Same for `nave` and `n`. Am I wrong?

Also, if this is an awful idea feel free to say so.

Docker is not an option. Long story. It may be available in the future.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that in my post... updating... but yes, Docker is absolutely the right choice here. Or, it should be. :/

Comment: Here is a discussion on the nvm github page that you may find useful https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/745

Comment: Thanks @AndyE, good discussion, very relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly install different versions of node using `nvm` or `nave` and invoke them for different applications on a server.

With `nvm` you would issue the command `nvm use 4`, for example, to set up the local environment to use Node 4.

Similarly, with `nave`, you would issue the command `nave use 6`. This command enters a subshell with the environment configured to use the indicated version of Node.